# How to fix a int overflow?

Tags: python, integer-overflow

I'm having a python code that uses the number `2637268776` (bigger than `sys.maxint` in 32-bit systems). Therefore it is saved as a `long` type.

I'm using a C++ framework bindings in my code, so I have a case where it's being converted into `int32`, resulting in an int32 overflow:

```
2637268776 --> -1657698520
```

In my case, it can happen only one time, so it's safe to assume that if the integer is negative, we had a single int overflow. How can I mathematically reverse the numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematically reverse"?

Comment: Can't you just use an unsigned 32bit integer?

Comment: The number you're showing can still be stored as an unsigned 32bit int. Now it depends on whether this holds for all numbers that you're using, or you need more than unsigned int can hold. I suppose this is difficult to guarantee, so you should try to use long int in the c++ side of the code or you'll run into the ambiguities NPE showed in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `2 * (sys.maxint + 1)` to it:

```
>>> -1657698520 + (2 * (sys.maxint + 1))
2637268776L
```

but that only works for original values < `2 * (sys.maxint + 1)`, as beyond that the overflow will run into positive numbers, or worse, overflow again.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you can't. There are many long integers that would map to the same negative number. In your example, these are 2637268776L, 6932236072L, 11227203368L, 15522170664L, 19817137960L etc.

Also, it is possible to get a *positive* number as a result of such an overflow. For example, 4294967297L would map to 1.